# Why Is My Smart Contract Not Able To Be Optimized?

Tags: solidity, remix, memory, compiler, stack

I have a smart contract that is barely below the limits of the solidity compiler.

When I try to enable optimization at 200 runs I get this error:

> CompilerError: Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly: Variable
> length is 7 slot(s) too deep inside the stack.

Why is it not able to optimize my code? Is this expected? Is there some bug in the solidity compiler optimizer? Do I just need to enable different settings for my compilation?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you using too many local variables or using a looping function which loops a lot? This error occurs in such cases usually.